# Get Object from imported CSV by named property

Tags: powershell

```
$Script = Import-Csv "C:\temp\script.csv"
$Script.GetType()
$Script
Write-Host $Script["0"].Body


IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                   
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                   
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

Title        Body                                                                                                                                                                     
-----        ----                                                                                                                                                                     
IntroMessage Intro message body
Testmessage  Test message body

Intromessage body
```

I have the above code working as expected, but I'm trying (and failing) to read out the objects in a more readable way. I.e. I'd like to be able to call each object using the title property rather than index, but I'm scratching my head here.

Comment: Show some lines of your input CSV file so we know what you're dealing with

Comment: @theo - the input isn't the problem, and I've shown above what the data look like, but here you go:

Title,Body
IntroMessage,Intro Message body
Testmessage,Test Message body

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a loop statement or perhaps the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
$Script |ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "This next object has the title $($_.Title)"
}
```

`$_` will refer to the current item in the collection being processed.

You could also use a `for` loop if you need to keep track of the index:

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $Script.Length; $i++){
    Write-Host "Object at index $i has the title $($Script[$i].Title)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Script = Import-Csv "C:\temp\script.csv"
```

You need to either use the index for the element in the `$Script` array and get the properties from that (i.e. `$Script[1].Body` --> "Test message body")

Or if you want to be able to get the Body part by using the Title, you need to convert this object array into a Hashtable:

```
# create a Hashtable where the Keys are the items 'Title' property and
# the Values are the items 'Body' property
$Bodies = @{}
$Script | ForEach-Object { $Bodies[$_.Title] = $_.Body }
```

Now you can use

```
$Bodies['IntroMessage']  # --> "Intro message body"
$Bodies['Testmessage']   # --> "Test message body"
```

Or .dot notation

```
$Bodies.IntroMessage  # --> "Intro message body"
$Bodies.Testmessage   # --> "Test message body"
```

Another option would be to leave the $Script (object) array as-is and filter with `Where-Object` clauses:

```
($Script | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq 'IntroMessage' }).Body  # --> "Intro message body"
($Script | Where-Object { $_.Title -eq 'Testmessage' }).Body   # --> "Test message body"
```

Comment: Agree hash is the way to go. However, in my experience adding to a hash using the `[Key] = ...` approach overrides.  If there are duplicate titles only the last one encountered will be in the hash.  That behavior obviously has it's uses, but if there's a chance of duplication, especially at the outset the `.Add(...)` method does a better job of exposing and handling it.

Comment: @Steven A Hashtable cannot have duplicate keys. Using `$hash['something'] =` does override so the last one 'wins'. With `$hash.Add(..)` an exception is thrown which you can ignore (--> first one wins) or you can change the title so it becomes unique and add the something under that changes key. However, both options have their disadvantages. If the OP wants to specify using the Title, he/she better make sure all titles are unique..

Comment: I wasn't being critical & I don't see a disagreement.  I like to start with `.Add()` to expose a duplication on the source side.  When I say duplicate I mean from the source data.  I do agree it's the OP's responsibility to ensure a unique key.  If there a re multiple instances of a title I structure the code to add an array as the value, sometimes I use `Group-Object` for it. Note: the OP may not have the option to alter the source data, furthermore it may be impractical to alter the title for the sake of unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm misreading the question, but if you want to refer to the objects using the title property you have to index them with a hash (dictionary) object.

```
$Script = @{} # Define an empty hash
Import-Csv "C:\temp\script.csv" |
ForEach-Object{
    If( !$Script.Contains($_.Title) )
    {
        $Script.Add( $_.Title, $_ )
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host "$($_.Title) is a duplicate key and cannot be added to the hash"
    }
}

# Now reference like:
$Script.'Testmessage' # will return the value/object at that key like:

<#
Title        Body                                                                                                                                                                     
-----        ----                                                                                                                                                                     
Testmessage  Test message body
#>
```

Note: You can also use the index format like `$Script['Testmessage']` to call back the value/object.

This assumes the titles are unique. If there are duplicate titles for discrete objects you can use a collection as the value.  If that's needed I can amend the answer with an example.  Of course the way the current example is written it will expose that issue if it exists.